# Generic protocol inside generic protocol in Swift 3

Tags: swift, generics, protocols

I want to create an interface (protocol) for Tree in Swift. This tree will use interface (protocol) for TreeNodes. But all these interfaces should be generic. Ideally I want to have something like this:

```
protocol TreeNodeInterface {
    associatedtype T: ElementInterface

    var value: T { get set }

    // ... some other methods
 }

protocol TreeInterface {
    var rootNode: TreeNodeInterface<T>? { get }

    func clean()

    // .. some other methods
}

class Tree<T: ElementInterface>: TreeInterface {
    var root: TreeNodeInterface<T>?

    var rootNode: TreeNodeInterface<T>? {
        get {
            return root
        }
    }

    func clean() {

    }
}
```

So for example I will have class Tree inherited from TreeInterface and I can initialize that Tree with any type (Int, String, CustomClass etc), so that each node will have that type as a value.

I managed to do this with Object Oriented Programming, but cannot do it with Protocol Oriented Programming

Swift doesn't allow me to do this. Can someone help me here?
Thanks

Comment: It's not clear what you're getting from protocols here (and getting this to work is not simple, so it's worth making sure it's worth it). Do you really expect multiple implementations of `TreeInterface`? What would a second implementation look like? Without protocols (or classes), this is fairly straightforward.

Comment: Next protocol can be BinaryTreeInterface, BinarySearchTreeInterface, AVLTreeInterface and so on. Same for TreeNodeInterface

Comment: I don't understand how "BinarySearchTreeInterface" is a protocol. That sounds like a specific implementation (perhaps that's what you really mean here). And what are the requirements of `ElementInterface`? That's creating a lot of complexity. I think you want to look at how `Collection` is implemented, and create a `Tree` protocol along the same lines. As described, I think this has become over-complicated and Swift will tend to fight you on over-complicated protocols. For example, if `rootNode` simply returns `T` rather than `TreeNodeInterface`, then this all dramatically simplifies.

Comment: Being "protocol oriented" does not mean "create a protocol for every piece and sub-piece of the system." That may be the confusion here. Again, `Collection` is the best place to start. Build from it to your `Tree` interface (and in Swift, that's just called `Tree`, not `TreeInterface`).

Comment: Yes, guys, you are right. I made things too complex. Thanks for your answers.

Comment: @RobNapier, why I wanted to use Protocols, is because I wanted to have some interface for BinaryTree, BST, AVL, etc. and several different implementations of all these trees, for example, one BST based on class, another one BST based on struct (value type), another one BST based on Enum etc. And I wanted to have interfaces for Trees, and trees' notes and they were supposed to have Generics, so that they could work with different types.

Comment: But Swift doesn't allow me to do this. It allows to have either class inheritance, or classes for each tree with "final" keyword. which is also not what I want. and if protocol has associatedtype and Self, I cannot use this protocol in function parameters etc.

Comment: Correct; you generally either need to add `where` clauses to the function or you need a type eraser. http://robnapier.net/erasure (Many, many Swift issues currently end in "type-eraser.") In Swift 4, associated types will be a bit stronger, which will make some things simpler (you'll be able to add `where` clauses to the associated type directly), but generally a better solution is to compose with generic strategies rather than complex protocols. http://www.thedotpost.com/2016/01/rob-napier-beyond-crusty-real-world-protocols

Comment: I'd be very thoughtful about having a single protocol w/ both reference and value semantics though. That would tend to violate the point of protocols, which include semantics, not just syntax. Two semantics in the same protocol makes generic algorithms harder (or impossible), not easier. https://oleb.net/blog/2016/12/protocols-have-semantics/

Comment: For building your protocol, I believe you want to get yourself back to "what can a consumer do with this thing." The point isn't "it's a tree" or even "I can call root() on it." There's no "Subscriptable" protocol, and that's on purpose. What can the caller do if they know it's a *tree* rather than a *collection*? What kinds of new generic algorithms can *only* be implemented on trees (but not any other kind of collection)? Without showing your consuming code, it's hard to help design the providing code.

Answer (score 1):

I think you're trying to do too much with protocols. Your biggest problem here is that you cannot create a variable with a protocol type if that protocol has an associated type (or a Self requirement). By replacing these definitions with generics, I ended up with this:

```
protocol TreeNodeInterface {
    associatedtype Element: ElementInterface

    var value: Element { get set }

    // ... some other methods
}

protocol TreeInterface {
    associatedtype Node: TreeNodeInterface

    var rootNode: Node? { get }

    func clean()

    // .. some other methods
}

class Tree<T: TreeNodeInterface>: TreeInterface {
    typealias Node = T
    var rootNode: T?

    init() {}

    func clean() {

    }
}
```

This compiles, but now you have to figure out how to initialize it. Next step is to make a type which conforms to `TreeNodeInterface`:

```
struct TreeNode<T: ElementInterface>: TreeNodeInterface {
    typealias Element = T
    var value: T
}
```

This looks strikingly similar to the protocol, but that's alright. Now let's initialize `Tree`:

```
// Assuming that Int conforms to ElementInterface
let tree = Tree<TreeNode<Int>>()
```

*Phew!* That was a lot of work, most of which I consider unnecessary. Do you really need `TreeNodeInterface` and `TreeInterface`? I'd argue that you don't. Here's what it might look like if you used concrete types instead:

```
struct TreeNode<T: ElementInterface> {
    var value: T
}

class Tree<T: ElementInterface> {
    var root: TreeNode<T>?

    init() {}

    func clean() {

    }
}

let tree = Tree<Int>()
```